# Is there an NCO command to change the time stamp of a variable in a netcdf?

Tags: netcdf, nco, timestep

I have a netcdf file containing maximum daily air temperature, time, lat and lon. I successfully got maximum temperature from a netcdf of 6 hourly temperatures using the nco command:

ncra -y max --mro -d time,,,4,4 6hourly.nc max.nc"

The only problem is, my time steps are still split into quarter days:

variables:

```
double lon(lon) ;
    lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
    lon:long_name = "lon" ;
    lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
double lat(lat) ;
    lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
    lat:long_name = "lat" ;
    lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
double time(time) ;
    time:units = "days since 0850-01-01 00:00:00" ;
    time:long_name = "time" ;
    time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
double tair(time, lat, lon) ;
    tair:units = "K" ;
    tair:_FillValue = 1.e+30 ;
    tair:long_name = "2 meter air temperature" ;
    tair:days\ since\ 850 = 0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1., 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2., 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3., 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4., 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5., 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6., 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7., 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8., 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9., 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10., 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11., 11.25, 11.5...
```

My question is, how do I change the time step for the 'days\ since\ 850' attribute in the variable tair, to whole numbers?

Thanks!

Charlotte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ncap2](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap_att) can work with attributes. However, you have a particularly thorny issue because your attribute name contains whitespace, and the attribute value is an array. I think in this case you need to first rename the attribute, then manipulate it. (Then you can rename it back if desired.):

```
ncrename -O -a "tair@days since 850",tair@days_since_850 in.nc foo.nc
ncap2 -O -s 'tair@days_since_850=int(tair@days_since_850)' foo.nc out.nc
```

Edit 20210209 in answer to comment below:
To copy an attribute from one variable to another, try

```
ncap2 -s 'var1@att1=var2@att2' in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie! Your suggestion worked for a month of data, but when I tried it on 1200 years of data (850-1200), it didn't work. I have netcdf's of other climate data with the attributes and variable in the format I'm looking for. Is there an nco command to copy attributes from one necdf to another?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has a similar problem, this ended up working for me:

```
ncap2 -s 'time=array(0,1,$time)' outmax.nc outmax2.nc
ncap2 -s 'time=array(0,1,$time)' outmin.nc outmin2.nc
```